# How to install Enthought Canopy packages on standalone machines?

Tags: enthought

How do I install Canopy packages if I am on a computer without an internet connection? Should I use the egginst.exe in the System sandbox or the user sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. The article in the Documentation entitled "Where are all of the Python packages in my User Python Environment" explains it well.  Canopy looks for packages in the following order user --> system --> canopy installation.

So login to your Enthought account and go to the repository. Download all the eggs you want and install with USERNAME\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts\egginst.exe

At least that seems to work for me.

Comment: Correct. Better not to mess with System!